# EventToCommand for Loaded event not working as expected if Window.SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight

Tags: mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I find out that the `EventToCommand` for the Loaded-event is not working as expected if the `Window.SizeToContent` attribute is set to `WidthAndHeight`.

The Loaded-event seems to be fired correctly, but the `EventToCommand.Command` property is bound AFTER the Loaded event is fired.

If `SizeToContent` is Manual the Command will be bound BEFORE Loaded is fired and it works as expected.

Does anyone also have problems with this behavior and/or an explanation for this?

My workaround for now is to bind to the `DataContext` of the window:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=DataContext.LoadedCommand}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Did you get any information that? Is this a WPF bug? We've spent quite a lot of time on that issue.

Comment: This obscure bug(?) is recently added dotnet github repository bug-tracker. I got bitten by this one too, slowly going insane thinking my XAML was some how borked.
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/429

Comment: @Dribbel ah, good to know... i'am used to think it's just my fault

Comment: @Samuel it seems that the problem is still present. did not tested it by myself, but due to the comments on [http://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/429](http://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/429)

Comment: still present in net framework 6 - thanks for the workaround