# Interaction EventTrigger ignores window Loaded event but not the others

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with interaction that should execute command when loaded:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ActivateCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DeactivateCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This is how it is used:

```
var loginVM = new Login();
var loginView = new Views.Login();
loginView.DataContext = loginVM;
loginView.ShowDialog();
```

When login view `DataContext` (view model) is set through xaml using view model locator, the `EventTrigger` works just fine and executes command on the VM.

However, if I set `DataContext` (view model) from code like in example above, the command on the view model does not get executed!?

I can also confirm that `Loaded` event is fired just before the window is shown, so after the `DataContext` has been set in the example... so data context is set, event fires but for some reason the command is not being called.

Any other event besides `Loaded` works flawlessly, so I am totally puzzled...

Comment: Have you considered passing the ``loginVM`` into the constructor and set the ``DataContext`` there?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that workaround... however just found the answer to the issue...

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I can confirm that this is a BUG, that occurs when you set `SizeToContent`:

Existence of SizeToContent in XAML breaks Loaded Event of window
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/429

[EventToCommand for Loaded event not working as expected if Window.SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627331/eventtocommand-for-loaded-event-not-working-as-expected-if-window-sizetocontent)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with VS2017 v15.5, Win10 v1709.16299.19, .net 4.7.1 (installed)

Comment: If you install .net 4.7.1 it will touch all from 4.0 to 4.7.x. It only matters what you have installed, not what is selected as target framework

Comment: Mine is 4.7 currentlly

Comment: i can confirm - vs22 netframework 6